# Joomla 25 (beez_20) template changes not having any affect

Tags: joomla

I have edited my beez_20 joomla 2.5 template..

> Editing file "index.php" in template "beez_20"

where the left menu is constructed by three jdoc statements.. (I added the ['s for this post)

> [jdoc:include type="modules" name="position-5" style="beezTabs" headerLevel="2"  id="3"]
>
> [jdoc:include type="modules" name="position-4" style="beezHide" headerLevel="3" state="0 "]
>
> [jdoc:include type="modules" name="position-7"  style="beezDivision" headerLevel="3"]

and I've reordered these three positions, intending to make modules in position-5 appear above modules in position-4.  By default, position 4 is on the top.

After making this change, the modules did not swap positions as I had expected.

I've cleared my browser cache and used a different browser, in case any xml/html was being cached.  I just think I'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you are modifying the order after this line:

```
<?php if ($navposition=='center' and $showleft) : ?>
```

However the positions you are using seem to be in another place. Look for this line (152 in mine):

```
<?php if ($navposition=='left' and $showleft) : ?>
```

Comment: You are exactly right.  I had not noticed that postions 4,5,7 appear in two places, dependent upon $navposition.  Thanks!